# harvard style referencing

Tags: natbib, harvard-style

I am new to LaTeX and I need to change the style of an article. 
Setting in tex file is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{dcu}
\begin{document}
\bibliography{final} 
\end{document}
```

An example in the bib file:

```
@article{Clement1999,
author = {Clement, A. and Cane, M. A. and Seager, R},
title = {{Orbital controls on the Tropical climate}},
journal = {Paleoceanography},
year = {1999},
volume = {14},
pages = {441--456}
}
```

It shows the referencing style in text and the list of references:

> (Simmons 1980)
>
> Simmons, N.M. (1980). Behaviour. In *The Desert Bighorn*, ed. G. Monson and L. Summer. Tucson, AZ: University of Arizona Press: 124-44.

I need to change the style to:

> (Simmons, 1980)
>
> Simmons, N.M. (1980). Behaviour. In *The Desert Bighorn*, ed. G. Monson and L. Summer. Tucson, AZ: University of Arizona Press, pp. 124-44.

I have tried the following ways to change the style:

`\bibliographystyle{dcu}` was changed to `\bibliographystyle{agsm}` the style remains the same in the pdf file after rerunning tex file. Rerunning of bib file showed this message:

> ! Missing $ inserted.
>
> ```
>             $
> ```
>
> ```
>                \mskip
> ```
>
> \,->\mskip
>
> ```
>        \thinmuskip
> ```
>
> l.440 ... of Florida Current transport at 27{\$}\,
>
> ```
>                                               ^\circ{\$}N}},
> ```

`\usepackage{natbib}` was changed to `\usepackage[comma]{natbib}`. Console output showed the message: `[comma] clash with natbib`.

`\cite{key}` was changed to `\citep{key}. After running the tex file, the style still remains the same (author year).` 

What should I do to show a comma between name and year in citation and to have 'pp.' instead of colon in references?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You say that "nothing changed" after you switched from the `dcu` style to the `agsm` style. Did you rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and Latex twice more after making the change? It does take two LaTeX runs *after* re-running BibTeX to fully propagate all changes.

Comment: Is `biblatex` an option?

Comment: Thank you for your tips, Mico. Usually I just rerun the tex file once (I  use TeXworks on windows). Then I can see the changes in the Pdf file. As you advised, I also rerun bib file. I am not sure if the rerun is successful as I got this message: 
440
Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
<to be read again> 
                   \mskip 
\,->\mskip 
           \thinmuskip 
l.440 ... of Florida Current transport at 27{\$}\,
                                                  ^\circ{\$}N}},

Answer (score 7):

> What should I do to show a comma between name and year in citation?

A: Load the `natbib` package with the option `comma` -- `\usepackage[comma]{natbib}` -- and use the command `\citep` to cite the piece in question.

The second question, which bibliography style to use to get the formatting the way you say you want it, is quite a bit harder to answer. As shown below, *none* of the style files that are belong to the [harvard](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/harvard) citation management package (two of which are `dcu` and `agsm`) deliver precisely what you say you want. Listed alphabetically by style file (and skipping over the somewhat specialized `nederlands` style), the formatting produced by the package's style files is as follows:

**agsm**

[image]

**apsr**

[image]

**dcu**

[image]

**jmr**

[image]

**jphysicsB**

[image]

**kluwer**

[image]

I'd say the `apsr` bibliography style comes closest to delivering the formatting you say you want -- although you'll probably have to enter by hand the comma that appears to be missing between the name of the publisher and the `pp` string...

Interestingly, all of these styles happen to prefix the string "pp. " before the contents of the `pages` field -- at least for entries of type `@incollection`.

Of course, there are *many, many* bibliography style files out there that can produce authoryear-style citations. You should certainly not feel constrained to choose from the just the half dozen of style files provided by "harvard" package.

---

*Addendum* to address some of the OP's follow-up comments:

- If the instruction `\usepackage[comma]{natbib}` gives you an error message along the lines you report, it's probably because the package has already been loaded (maybe by the document class you're using). In fact, your MWE loads the `natbib` package *twice*. If you add the option `comma` to the second `\usepackage{natbib}` instruction you're guaranteed to get the error message you report getting.

  If you can't get rid of the first, incompatible `\usepackage{natbib}` statement, executing the instruction

  ```
  \setcitestyle{aysep={,}}
  ```

  should work. See p. 12 of the `natbib` package's user guide for more on the `\setcitestyle` macro.
- Because your MWE doesn't feature a `\cite` or `\nocite` command, the instruction `\bibliography{final}` will not produce any output. Your MWE is also missing the instruction `\usepackage{amsmath}`; without it the preamble instruction `\numberwithin{equation}{section}` will cause an error. Separately, if you want to use `hyperref`, you should load `hyperref` *after* `natbib`; and, if you want the citation callouts to be made into hyperlinks to the corresponding bibliographic entries,
- It looks like you have a typo in the sentence on the Florida Current. I would try

  ```
  Florida Current transport at 27\,${}^{\circ}$N
  ```

  At any rate, this matter does not look to be related directly to citations and bibliography generation, right? It looks like an "ordinary" LaTeX syntax error to me...

A fully modified/corrected version of your MWE produces the following output. (Be sure to run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more on the file.) Note the comma between the author string and the year string in the citation callout.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % this was missing in your code
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{natbib}   % no point in loading a package more than once...
\setcitestyle{aysep={,}} 
\bibliographystyle{dcu}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue]% %% added these two options
   {hyperref} % hyperref should be loaded _after_ natbib
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{final.bib}
@article{Clement1999,
   author  = {Clement, A. and Cane, M. A. and Seager, R.},
   title   = {{Orbital controls on the Tropical climate}},
   journal = {Paleoceanography},
   year    = {1999},
   volume  = {14},
   pages   = {441--456}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\citep{Clement1999}  %% need at least one \cite, \citet, or \citep command...
\bibliography{final} 
\end{document}
```

---

Here's the MWE that was used to create the first set of screen shots shown above.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[comma]{natbib}
\usepackage{har2nat}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
  %% or: apsr, dcu, jmr, jphysicsB, kluwer
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{simmons:1980,
   author    = "N. M. Simmons",
   title     = "Behaviour",
   pages     = "124-44",
   year      = 1980,
   booktitle = "The Desert Bighorn",
   editor    = "Gale Monson and Lowell Summer",
   publisher = "University of Arizona Press",
   address   = "Tucson, AZ",
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}
\citep{simmons:1980}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually, I am editing the article for a publication of Cambridge University Press. I thought the referencing style shouldn't be uncommon. I changed \usepackage{natbib} to \usepackage[comma]{natbib} then reran the tex file. Console output shows a message: [comma] option clash with nitbib. Then I switched it back to \usepackage{natbib} and used the command \citep instead of \cite. After rerunning the tex file a few times, the style is still (author year) and there is no comma in between.

Comment: @Kendra - Without more detailed information about your document setup it's going to be close to impossible to diagnose fully what's going on. Regarding the option clash, it seems likely (though I can't be sure without getting more information) that the `natbib` package has already been loaded earlier by your file -- maybe by the class file itself. Please consider editing your query and adding an MWE (minimum working example) that reproduces the issues you're looking to solve.

Comment: Hi Mico, thank you for your suggestion. I have edited my question and included part of the setting of the tex file. I hope it is fine this time.

Comment: @Kendra - I've posted an addendum to my answer to address your follow-up comments and some of the issues raised by the new material you posted in your query.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mico. Just a quick response. The tex file I received works perfectly. There are a lot of usepackages and commands in the preamble and I don't know what are crucial to put in the MWE. The \usepackage{amsmath} is in the setting. Anyway, I need to read your answer carefully again and then work on the problem. Thank you very much again!